# Embed Database to WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, database, embed, portability

How to embed a database to a WPF application?

> **scenario:** this is our school project and we are required to create a
>   system with a database. now, i have done the fundamentals (create a
>   database, creating a layout and the c# code for programability) but
>   now, when we are to transfer the build onto a different computer, the
>   database seems to be lost.

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 with SQL Server for its database and that database is placed within the localdb of my computer. what i want is a portable system so that we can present the system anywhere without the hassle of bringing my desktop to school.

thanks in advance <3

> **EDIT:** there are a ton of ways to connect a database to a wpf
>   application and i dont know what to choose. theres the ling-to-sql,
>   entity framework, data source etc. which of these methods will be the
>   best way for a portable application with the database in it.

Comment: I use SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) which comes with SQL Server.  I deattach the database (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188031.aspx).  The database is in a folder like : C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\..  I then copy the database mdf and ldf file to new computer is same folder.  The reattach using SSMS by right clicking on Database and selecting ATTACH.  To move file I zip the mdf and ldf and email it to myself.

Comment: the problem is that the workstation for presentation that we will be using doesn't have any database developer tools. what i want to do is literaly include the database into the application for portability. just like plug and play no need for setup just open the applicaton and present it to our panels

Comment: SSMS doesn't require a database and can be installed on any without a license.  If can be installed on any PC and connect to a remote PC provided the credentials are correct.  Like wise a c# application can connect to a remote SQL Server provided the credentials are set up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

my WPF app uses SQL Compact + Entity Framework (code first) + migrations, yo can find sources here https://github.com/tym32167/arma3beclient

All database-related things placed in this project https://github.com/tym32167/arma3beclient/tree/master/src/Arma3BE.Client.Libs

Data context here https://github.com/tym32167/arma3beclient/blob/master/src/Arma3BE.Client.Libs/Context/Arma3BEClientContext.cs

Migrations here https://github.com/tym32167/arma3beclient/tree/master/src/Arma3BE.Client.Libs/Migrations